# Power Query - Concatenate and Transpose

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I"ve a data table (1) below and want the result as in table (2). How can I do this?

[image: Click here to check the table 1 and 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

- Delete duplicate rows using Remove Rows > Remove Duplicates
- Group your table using concatenation ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058355/powerquery-how-can-i-concatenate-grouped-values))
- Split the concatenated `State` column using Split Column > By Delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    group = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {{"State", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([State]), "|")}}),
    split = Table.SplitColumn(group, "State", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"State.1", "State.2", "State.3"})
in
    split
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXWC4.png)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look a this topic: [VBA excel, concatenate cells when there are duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342939/vba-excel-concatenate-cells-when-there-are-duplicates/14343248#14343248) .

You could use that vlookupall function and then use "Text to column" on your result.